# List networks I'm hardwired to

Tags: networking

In windows 10, the Network Sharing Centre tells me which is my active network. Is it possible to list all the networks in my building?

In my building, we have 2 networks. One of the machines, on "network 1", has a share setup with a machine on "network 2". I wondered if there's a way of seeing all networks so I don't have to wonder over to the other machine to find out what network it is on.

Comment: You need to be connected to both networks, so two network adapters.

Comment: Hard wired networks aren't usually identified, unless it's by the domain managing that network. What sort of identification do these networks currently have?